# Android Studio could not detect SDK

Tags: java, android

After installing Android SDK, Gradle and JDR, JRE on Linux, Android Studio could not detect SDK in `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_11`.

IntelliJ IDE does not have any problem and everything is OK. But android studio displays this error:

```
No Android SDK found. Please configure an Android SDK.
```

the path of the SDK is the same as for IntlliJ IDE.

`.bashrc` content:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre-8-oracle-i586
```

Other Information:

`sudo update-alternatives --config java`

```
[sudo] password for tux-world: 
There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                     Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/jre-8-oracle-i586/bin/java   317       auto mode
* 1            /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_11/bin/java         1         manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/jre-8-oracle-i586/bin/java   317       manual mode
```

How to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you downloaded any SDK from Android SDK Manager? or you just installed the SDK manager?